# How to transfer parameters to the next page，html, javascript,

Tags: javascript, html

my one page  https://www.xxxx.com/mypage.html

```
<form id="form1"  method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="email" value="myemail@gmail.com" />
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to click Submit. This page directe to  https://www.bing.com
This value myemail@gmail.com,
Display in the bing search box. How to do.

bing search box  id="sb_form_q"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

You have to redirect to `https://www.bing.com/search?q=myemail@gmail.com`

You can't pass data directly to other page if owner doesn't allow it. It would be an XSS vulnerability otherwise.